# outlook api giving error code request parameter missing

Tags: api, outlook

I am working on [outlook api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx#contact) and i am getting the following error code in response

```
"error": {
      "code": "request_parameter_missing", 
      "message": "The request entity body is missing a required parameter. The request must include at least one of these parameters: 'first_name', 'last_name', 'emails', 'employer'."
   }
```

here is my code

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

$access_token = TOKEN;
$api_url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts?&access_token=".$access_token;

$curl = curl_init($api_url);
$curl_data = array(
    'first_name' => "Roberto",
    'last_name' => "Tamburello"
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
echo"<pre>";
print_r($curl_response);

echo "</pre>";
```

I have been searching for few hours now and i cant seem to understand what am i doing wrong. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this too. For me the content type header wasn't set correctly to "application/json" and therefore even though the data was there, it didn't recognise it. Fixing this removed the error for me.
Not sure exactly where your problem is but thought this might help others. Here is my request in .net

```
    var requestUrl = " https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts";

    //set body data
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(liveContact); 
    //liveContact is a custom object for storing contact data
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

    WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl);
    req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + "...access token...");
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentType = "application/json";
    req.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    using (Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream()) {
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
    }

    using (WebResponse response = await req.GetResponseAsync()) {
        using (var dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream)) {
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```